# Orientation of the image of a regular surface under a rigid motion

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface with orientation $N$, and suppse $f$ is a rigid motion of $\mathbb{R}^3$. We know the image $\tilde{S}=f(S)$ is a regular surface. I want to show that the function $\tilde{N}:\tilde{S}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\tilde{N}(f(p))=df_p(N)$ for $p\in S$ provides an orientation of $\tilde{S}$. But I am getting stuck on some details.

In my course, we define an orientation of $S$ as a unit normal field on $S$.

**Attempted solution**

Let $p\in S$. We want to show $df_p(N(p))$ is a unit normal vector to $f(S)$ at $f(p)$. Take a chart $\sigma:U\to S$ and let $q=\sigma^{-1}(p)$. As rigid motions are diffeomorphisms, the composite $f\circ\sigma$ gives us a chart for $f(S)$. Then $$N(p)=\frac{\sigma_u(q)\times\sigma_v(q)}{|\sigma_u(q)\times\sigma_v(q)|}.$$ The chain rule gives us $(f\circ\sigma)_u(q) = \sigma_u(q)f_u(\sigma(q)) = \sigma_u(q)f_u(p)$. But I am not sure how the cross product of this with $(f\circ\sigma)_v(q) = \sigma_v(q)f_v(p)$ can give us a nice form like $df_p(N(p))$.

Comment: If $f$ is a rigid motion, then it's differential map is an isometry. Isometries preserve angles, dot and cross products. In other words:
$df_p (\sigma_u(q)\times \sigma_v(q)) = df_p (\sigma_u(q)) \times df_p (\sigma_v(q))$.

Comment: I somehow always miss these seemingly obvious observations. I should be able to solve this problem on my own now. Thanks!